# showing that ito's integral on brownian motion normalized by bessel process is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csSbk.png)

I couldn't prove (ii), I've tried to use levy's theorem together with (i) (and also without (i)) but it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I think Levy's theorem should work.  We have that $X$ is a continuous local martingale because it's a stochastic integral, so we just need to check $\langle X, X \rangle_t  = t$.  We compute

\begin{align*}
\langle X, X \rangle_t   &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_0^t \left( \frac 1R W^i \right)^2 ds \\
&=  \int_0^t  \frac 1{R^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \left(W^i \right)^2 ds \\
&= \int_0^t  \frac 1{R^2} |W|^2 ds \\
&= \int_0^t ds = t
\end{align*}

so by Levy's characterization, $X$ is a Brownian motion.

Comment: the levy's theorem I know requires to prove that x and x^2-t are martingales, why taking the following product is correct (your first line)? if I am allowed to do that then I guess it will work .i got stuck in the first place because of  the crossover terms of the integrals (itegral over dwi multiplied by integral over dwj)

Comment: The statement $X^2-t$ is a martingale is equivalent to $\langle X,X \rangle_t = t$, so this is the same Levy's theorem.  The reason the cross terms go away is because $W^i$ and $W^j$ are independent when $i \ne j$

Comment: but you still have 1/R in both integrals, so they are not fully independent

Comment: We still have $\langle W^i,W^j \rangle = 0$, though, so it doesn't matter what we are integrating.

Comment: I think that I haven't stated that the question is talking about the sum of the integrals, not a vector of them

Comment: Yes, I looked at the image to find that out.  I used it in my answer, so I'm not sure what the issue is?